# How do I block access to files across OSes [Windows/Linux]?

Tags: windows-10, ntfs

Is it possible to block access to some files/folders from outside of a Windows account?

e.g. if I boot the PC with a Linux live-USB, I can access all the files within the NTFS partitions and I'd like to avoid that

Answer (score 1):

Encryption. The only way.

macOS can be told to ignore permissions on any volume it is not booted from, making it trivial to read data from it.

*After comments*
I had originally claimed all OSes can do this, but after multiple comments below I'm not sure if they can. There appears to be some debate as to whether this is possible on any other OS.
However, give me any boot or data drive & I can read it, so long as I mount it to another machine. I've been doing it for more years than I can remember. I exclusively use a Mac to analyse & fix various drives from other OSes & never once had any difficulty so long as they're not encrypted.
There's just a checkbox to switch off permissions.
I use the Mac to do this for several reasons, one is that simple checkbox, the other is the simplicity of fixing/cloning/rescuing non-Mac drives compared to doing it under native conditions or from command-line 'live' unix rescue solutions.

A simple example with 2 volumes mounted on a Mac. One is a direct clone of the other, though not absolutely up to date so they are not literally identical. Both are bootable volumes, of course. The one on the left is the current boot volume, the other merely mounted as  any other internal drive.
The non-boot volume has a simple switch to ignore permissions, giving me unlimited access, unfettered by any restriction applied while it is the boot volume. Note the permissions are already slightly different, as the OS itself does not claim to 'own' the filesystem on the clone. If I swap which drive I'm booted from, these permissions will swap one to the other, as will the 'ignore ownership' flag.

[image]

Comment: "No OS respects permissions applied to a non-boot drive" is demonstrably wrong: If I boot my Linux PC, later plug in an extX-formated USB-drive (obviously a "non-boot drive") permissions there are enforced. I do agree on crypto being the only reliable way though.

Comment: Give me any boot drive & I can read it, so long as I mount it to another machine. I've been doing it for more years than I can remember. i exclusively use a Mac to analyse & fix various drives from other OSes & never once had any difficulty so long as they're not encrypted. There's just a checkbox to switch off permissions.

Comment: @EugenRieck The reason why what you experienced occurred is because ext-variants are a Linux filesystem with UGO permissions, which is what all UNIX-based OSes [BSD/Linux] use. Windows uses NTFS exclusively since XP, using ACLs for more granular permissions that UGO doesn't offer _(ACLs are often used as a generic term for referring to permissions in general [like kleenex], but not in this context - see [`icacls`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/icacls))_, which Linux/BSD has no way of enforcing.

Comment: It is still a "non-boot drive". So the answer stays wrong in a trivially demonstrable way.  And you don't need NTFS to demonstrate non-unix-type permissions ... just use FAT (none at all)

Comment: @EugenRieck - I'm really not sure what point you're trying to make. Bypassing privileges on any drive a computer is not booted from is trivially simple. Use any filesystem you like, you cannot enforce privileges. The OS can simply be told to ignore them.If you happen to be using an OS that cannot do this, then swap to one that can (which would mitigate my claim that **no** OS respects permissions, but doesn't make the end result any different.)

Comment: @Tetsujin befored you edited your answer it was reading `No OS respects permissions applied to a non-boot drive` this is ofcourse horribly wrong. All I did was make this clear.

Comment: I’m afraid Eugen is right here: Both Windows and Linux will absolutely enforce permissions/ACLs anywhere. The problem stems from the fact that I can become root/Administrator easily on an OS I control, enabling me to override/ignore/change those permissions.

Comment: @EugenRieck - I've changed this to essentially "macOS can be told to ignore perms". Until someone comes back to me to state this can or can't be done on other OSes, then I'll stick to that. The end result is still that it is absolutely trivial to achieve.

Comment: @DanielB - sorry, can't flag 2 people in one comment. Please check/confirm the other comments & answer changes.

Comment: In my experience, it's also trivial to ignore any and all access restrictions on a non-boot drive using Linux or Windows. The fact that those OS's can be set to act otherwise is irrelevant to what the Question is about.

Comment: @kreemoweet - that was my thought too. Whether it **normally** would respect permissions is unimportant compared to whether that 'respect' can simply be switched off by some simple method.